# The ordinal 341 could not be located

Tags: mongodb

The ordinal 341 could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe

I've replace the libeay32.dll and SSLeay.32.dll but still not working.

Anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

FYI, I'm running Windows 10 (x64)

Answer (score -1):

Add a text file called  c:\MongoDB\mongod.cfg that contains the following;

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: c:\mongodb\data\log\mongodb.log
   logAppend: true
storage:
    dbPath: c:\mongodb\data\db
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017
```

and then run service like this

**mongod.exe -f C:\MongoDB\mongod.cfg**